# Why rotation causes twisting stress?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, stress-strain

Measuring stress of a rotating shaft is a way of measuring the torque and power transmitted by the shaft.

But in which way rotation of a shaft causes stress?

Comment: Check out https://measurementsensors.honeywell.com/techresources/appnotes/Pages/Ways_to_Measure_the_Force_Acting_on_a_Rotating_Shaft.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually speaking, a shaft transmits torque from some power source to some load.

If we have a clockwise torque applied to a shaft by a power source, the shaft transmits a clockwise torque to a load. At the same time, due to Newton's third law, the load applies a counterclockwise torque the shaft.

As a result, there are two oppositely directed torques acting on the two ends of the shaft and, naturally, causing a twisting (or torsional) stress.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the rotation, it's torque applied against resistance. It could occur for a stationary shaft that is trying to initiate rotation, for example.